# How to implement spherical environment map with 360 degree texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, mapping

When we create cubemap in OpenGl, we need six images and with these, we can create cubemap. (simply put, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)

At first, I guessed there was similar parameter such as GL_TEXTURE_SHPHERE_MAP,
but I could't find any thing related to it.

I wonder how we can create spherical environment map with 360 degree images?

(If you know the site about that, please link for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder how we can create spherical environment map with 360 degree images?

Load the image as a regular 2D texture and do spherical texture coordinate mapping in the shader.